# How do I turn the auto-filled background an image turned into a button from purple into white using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am just wondering how to clear up the purple portion of the image and turn it into white.

```
kotlin
@Composable
fun generateButtons(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val mContext = LocalContext.current
    var mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.shush1)
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(1F, 1F)
    Row(){
        Button(onClick = { mediaPlayer.start() }) {
            Image(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.play),
                contentDescription = "Play")
            ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.White)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: How the build appears]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `IconButton` instead.

```
IconButton(
    onClick = {},
) {
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.play),
        contentDescription = "Play"
    )
}
```

Or apply `ButtonColors` properly through `Button` params.

```
Button(
    onClick = {},
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.White),
) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.play),
        contentDescription = "Play"
    )
}
```

You could also check out the [Material Design system icons](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/icons/Icons).

```
IconButton(onClick = {}) {
    Icon(
        Icons.Default.PlayArrow,
        contentDescription = "Play"
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Modifier to change the background colour.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White))
```